# Json - Invalid UTF-8 sequence

Tags: php, json, encode

I received the following error message and I dont know how to fix it:
"PHP Warning:  json_encode() [function.json-encode]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence" at this php script:

```
<?
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT *
  FROM produse_comenzi
  JOIN comenzi 
    ON comenzi.id_comanda = produse_comenzi.id_comanda
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura, id_comanda FROM facturi) AS facturi
    ON facturi.id_comanda = comenzi.id_comanda
    AND comenzi.data >= '". $_GET['i'] ."' AND comenzi.data <= '". $_GET['d'] ."'
    JOIN produse ON produse.id_produs = produse_comenzi.id_produs");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: What's the content of your table? It seems it contains some multibyte chars, take a look inside

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows[] = mb_check_encoding($r, 'UTF-8') ? $r : utf8_encode($r)
```

try this one before the print statement.

Comment: Do you mean `$rows[] = mb_check_encoding($r, 'UTF-8') ? $r : utf8_encode($r)` inside the while statement? :)

Comment: I received this error: PHP Warning:  mb_check_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: because you will have do it for all the data you are getting from the database separately